# Dollar Sign "\$" in Regular Expressions with word boundaries "\b" (PHP / JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, regex, dollar-sign, word-boundary

I am aware that the issue involving the dollar sign "$" in regex (here: either in PHP and JavaScript) has been discussed numerous times before: Yes, I know that I need to add a backslash "\" in front of it (depending on the string processing even two), but the correct way to match a dollar sign is "\$". ... Been there, done that, works fine.

---

But here's my new problem: Dollar signs "\$" next to word boundaries marked with "\b". ... My following examples can easily be reproduced on e.g. regexpal.com.

Let's start with the following text to search in:

> Dollar 50
>
> Dollars 50
>
> $ 50
>
> USD 50

My regex should find either "USD", "Dollar", or "$". Easy enough: Let's try

> (USD|Dollar|\$)

Success: It finds the "$", the "USD", and both "Dollar" occurrences, including in "Dollars".

But let's try to skip the "Dollars" by adding word boundaries after the multiple choice:

> (USD|Dollar|\$)\b

And this is trouble: "USD" is matched, "Dollar" is matched, "Dollars" is rejected ... But the single, properly backslashed (or escaped) "$" is rejected as well, although that worked just a second before.

It's not related to the multiple choice inside the brackets: Try just

> \$

vs.

> \$\b

and it's just the same: The first one matches the dollar sign, the second one doesn't.

---

Another finding:

> (USD|Dollar|\$) \b

with a blank " " between the ")" and the "\b" actually works. But that workaround might not be viable under all circumstances (in case there should be a non-whitespace word boundary).

---

It seems that the escaped dollar sign refuses to be found when word boundaries are involved.

I'd love to hear your suggestions to solve this mystery. -- Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions): *"A word boundary matches the position where a word character is not followed or preceeded by another word-character."* However, `$` and spaces are not a word characters.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't match, because in `$` there isn't a word boundary immediately after the `$`. There would be, however, if a word started immediately after the `$` - for example

> $Millions

will match.

What you probably want to do is to make the `\b` apply only to those cases where you really do want to match a word boundary - for example

```
(USD\b|Dollar\b|\$)
```

This will insist on there being a word boundary after "USD" and after "Dollar", but not after "$".